# LINQ Clear() don't remove rows from database

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a db-table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemPrice
(
    [Identity]    INT    IDENTITY,
    Item_FK       INT    NOT NULL   REFERENCES Item([Identity]),
    PriceList_FK  INT    NOT NULL   REFERENCES PriceList([Identity]),
    Price         FLOAT  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Identity])
)
```

If i then in my linq context use the `Clear()` on one of my `PriceList` instances like this where `Current` is a `PriceList`:

```
Current.ItemPrices.Clear();
```

The items in `ItemPrice` is not removed. `PriceList_FK` is just set to `NULL` and then the DB conflicts on the `NOT NULL`.

How do i force the database to remove all the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did was jut simply to call remove on the Table itself, not clear on the referring Objects, like this:

```
Database.Accounting.ItemPrices.DeleteAllOnSubmit(Current.ItemPrices);
```

(Accounting is the Linq data context)